# Why does ls color two supposedly similar files differently?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, ls

So, here's the peculiar situation:

```
$ ls -l foo.sqlite foo.ssqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 xie xie 8192 Jan 22 19:25 foo.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 xie xie 8192 Jan 23 11:48 foo.ssqlite
```

In the output, `foo.sqlite` is colored blue by `ls` while `foo.ssqlite` is colored red/pink. Permissions are the same, types are the same:

```
$ file foo.sqlite foo.ssqlite
foo.sqlite:  SQLite 3.x database, last written using SQLite version 3026000
foo.ssqlite: SQLite 3.x database, last written using SQLite version 3023001
```

The only obvious difference is that `foo.sqlite` was created by a Perl script, while the other - by a Python script, however that does not explain the different coloring, as if `ls` recognizes these as two different file types. Well, the question then is why does `ls` report these in different colors despite the type being the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `ls` relies on environment variable `$LS_COLORS`. Doing `echo "$LS_COLORS" | grep --color  sqlite` revealed an entry with value `*.sqlite=38;5;147`, which apparently is the [256-color ANSI escape color code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in form `ESC[38;5;#m` for foreground color.